# PHP PDO fetch all tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I know with a standard mysql call we can do `mysql_list_tables` , however is there an equivalent while using PDO? If so, does this return an array? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Execute the query with `PDO::query()`:

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

If you fetch an associative array, the name of the column will be:

```
Tables_in_databasename
```

Note: this will list both tables and views.  If you must get **only tables**, use this instead:

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE
  TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA='yourdatabasename';
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Correct in t minus 7 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

Do `$pdo->query("show tables");` to obtain a result set of tables contained in the current database.

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = $db->query("show tables");
```

You can then do fetch on it.

Answer (score 3):

try this query :

```
"SHOW TABLES"
```